# UI glitches of SFSE in Firefox and Chrome and missing filter at User

Tags: feature-request, bug, ui

As of today, I notice some small UI bugs here in SFSE. In the black header-bar on the top, there are additional text-links which are breaking the layout. I have cleared the browser cache, but did not help. Tested with FF33.1 and Chrome38.0.2125.11 m

Also I noticed, that at Users, "Sort by reputation", there is no longer the "All Time" filter but max. "Year". Would be great to get it back.

It looks like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The header-bar is fixed, but the filter is still missing (first screenshot)

Comment: I'm seeing bugs in Chrome too. Went to edit a post and the preview window shrunk down to less than the height of 1 text line. Made it totally unreadable. Was fine earlier this AM.

Answer (score 2):

Latest release must have screwed something up. It doesn't appear like functionality is broken from what I have seen, but I am guessing they will fix it soon enough.